# How to know who of your Team members on appstoreconnect delete Development provisioning profile

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

is it possible to know when provisioning profile is deleted who delete it from the team or it's not?

Answer (score 0):

For provisioning profiles, you don't get notified when they are deleted.

---

For certificates, they email everyone on the team about the event that the certificate has been revoked.

I don't think you get the information about who deleted it, but it was surely someone on the team since it's the only way to access them.

[image]

Comment: I used to get that email when a certificate is revoking but when a provisioning profile deleted. i haven't received any emails.

Comment: updated answer. I've just deleted some provisioning profiles and did not get notified, there is also nowhere to look for logs.

Comment: Ok, Thanks For your time.